# RegisterClassEx in Assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm32

I'm trying to manually call RegisterClassEx Windows API without using a WNDCLASS structure on .data section, I need to create this structure only using `push` instruction.

Could someone help me on that please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: why do you need assembly to do this?

Comment: @joni: he don't need assembly to do it. He just *want* to do this in assembly :)

Comment: As one of these "I'm-cool-because-I-write-win32/64-apps-in-asm-just-for-fun-and-to-learn-something"-heroes, he should be able to figure it out by himself then to earn the medal :P

Comment: Yeah... I'm trying to create the WNDCLASS structure without using the .data segment.

Comment: @joni: and what makes you think that he is this kind of guy? Why an assembly question should generate this kind of comment? And if he is just learning what's going on inside the Windows APIs? You don't need to answer the question if you know the answer, but you should not discourage the guy with these comments. All kind of knowledge it's valid and welcome. I'm not defending him, I'm defending the **question**.

Comment: http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=21812.0 ? or you could model it together by hand using a hex editor :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you can easily do what you want. You just need to be careful to correctly calculate the addresses of each element of the structure. But this is also an easy task... ;)

Please check out the code I did:

```
WinMain:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    add esp, -50h

    push 7F00h
    push 0h
    call LoadIconA

    mov ebx, eax

    push 7F00h
    push 0h
    call LoadCursorA
    ;eax = return of LoadCursorA
    ;ebx = return of LoadIconA

    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-30h], 30h                 ;WNDCLASSEX.cbSize,           dd    WNDCLASSEX_size
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-2Ch], 3h                  ;WNDCLASSEX.style,            dd    CS_VREDRAW + CS_HREDRAW
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-28h], WndProc             ;WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc,      dd    WndProc
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-24h], 0h                  ;WNDCLASSEX.cbClsExtra,       dd    NULL
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-20h], 0h                  ;WNDCLASSEX.cbWndExtra,       dd    NULL
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-1Ch], 0h                  ;WNDCLASSEX.hInstance,        dd    NULL
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-18h], ebx                 ;WNDCLASSEX.hIcon,            dd    return of LoadIconA
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-14h], eax                 ;WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm,          dd    return of LoadCursorA
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-10h], 06h                 ;WNDCLASSEX.hbrBackground,    dd    COLOR_BTNFACE + 1
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-0Ch], 0h                  ;WNDCLASSEX.lpszMenuName,     dd    NULL
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-08h], offset WndProc      ;WNDCLASSEX.lpszClassName,    dd    offset of ClassName
    mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-04h], ebx                 ;WNDCLASSEX.hCursor,          dd    return of LoadIconA

    lea eax,[ebp-30h]
    push eax
    call RegisterClassEx
```

You just need to put this before the call to CreateWindow.

Any doubt just shout.

PS.: Remember that WndProc is the loop procedure of your Assembly program

Comment: `ss:` is not needed - it's default segment register for ebp.

Comment: @Abyx: yep I know, just for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.data 
    wndclass WNDCLASS
.code
    push offset wndclass
    call RegisterClassEx
```

You should push its offset, not structure itself

For local variable, push its address

```
 LOCAL wndclass:WNDCLASS
 lea edx, wndclass
 push edx
 call RegisterClassEx
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse **push** the structure to the stack, **push** the effective address to the first item, **call** RegisterClassEx, **pop** the structure off the stack.